# Using a variable as the property name for another object in handlebars

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I have 2 arrays of objects, one containing a list of objects with some information under property names like FirstName, LastName, PhoneNum..., and the other array stores a list of strings that matches up with the names of the properties of the first array. Made a small example below:

```
Array1 = [ {FirstName: John, LastName: Doe, PhoneNum: 123},
           {FirstName: Bob, LastName: Smith, PhoneNum: 456} ]
Array2 = [ "FirstName", "PhoneNum" ]
```

How can I use the second array's values to determine which property to display:

This is what I currently have:

```
{{#each MemberDetails}}
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-1 vert-align">
        <!-- ....... -->
    </td>
    {{#each ../MemberDesc}}
      <td class="vert-align">{{../{{this}} }}</td>  <--- This is what I'm trying to do
    {{/each}}
    <td class="vert-align">
        <!-- ....... -->
    </td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Handlebar doesn't support nested variables, so that code doesn't work, but anyone know a way for me to do this?

Comment: I think it's better to do your array manipulation in the node.js code and supply only the required fields in handlebar in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking into another completely different problem, I stumbled across the answer! Handlebars comes with the lookup helper function, which does exactly what I need. Here is the new code:

```
{{#each MemberDetails}}
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-1 vert-align">
        <!-- ....... -->
    </td>
    {{#each ../MemberDesc}}
      <td class="vert-align">{{lookup ../this this}}</td> 
    {{/each}}
    <td class="vert-align">
        <!-- ....... -->
    </td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

The `../this` references the current item in the outer loop, and the lookup function uses the second argument `this` as the key for the first argument.

I ended up doing what Tolsee said in his comment though, but still good to know that this option is available.